# Concurrent updates to the same row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out what is supposed to happen in MySQL/InnoDB if I issue the following 2 queries from different clients at the same time:

```
UPDATE tbl SET a=a+1 WHERE id=123;
UPDATE tbl SET b=b+1 WHERE id=123;
```

Provided the queries are done without an explicit transaction or explicit earlier locks set up earlier, the way the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locks-set.html) explains it, each query will try to get a `next-key` lock, so effectively a record lock on the updated rows.

Do I understand it right, that the worst outcome would be one query waiting on the lock until the other one finishes? There's no chance of an exception on conflict here, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. The two update operations will be serialized one after the other. Their order is very hard to predict, so you should not try.

If a third query asks `SELECT a, b FROM tbl WHERE id=123` at more or less the same time, that query will be serialized, unpredictably, with the others. So it may happen before, between, or after the other two.

Both update queries will eventually complete.  It takes more than these queries to cause a deadlock.

Comment: how slow will this be? how many updates on a row is possible in a second? Since for each concurrent update it will lock and unlock the row again and again.

Comment: This serialization adds very little time to the execution of the queries. They just run in order. As for how many updates per second you can get, how much money do you have? Server size and config determine that kind of number.